# Is there a way to autofocus keyboard in webview textinput field in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-inappwebview, keyboard-focus

I am using [InAppWebView](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) to show the webpage in a flutter app. Here keyboard is shown only when I tap on the input field. Is there a way that the keyboard is visible before tapping on the input field? The keyboard should appear right after navigating to this screen. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';


class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewScreen> createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}

class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrlRequest:
                URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('https://www.google.com')),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              print('onWebViewCreated');
            },
            onProgressChanged:
                (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
              print('onProgressChanged: $progress');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [`addUserScript`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/InAppWebViewController/addUserScript.html) method gives method implementation error.

And using [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example) plugin, it works:

```
class WebViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: "https://google.com",
      onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
        String jsStr = "window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {"
            "let i = document.getElementsByTagName('input');"
            "i[0].focus();"
            "console.log('done');"
            "});";
        webViewController.runJavascript(jsStr);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The Javascript executes, but it does not really put focus or cursor unless user taps on webview